# Permission denied issue in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

PHP Fatal error in laravel 5.1:

> Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream
>   or file "/var/www/html/SocialNet/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not
>   be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in
>   /var/www/html/SocialNet/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:13090\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/SocialNet/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13030)

Comment: It happens everyday and every minute also

Comment: Its telling you that it could not open the log file.  Once oyu have sorted that out, it will tell what is actually wrong.

Comment: Yeah chmod 777 filename and chown apache:apache filename

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 storage

Comment: change it but i again get that issue @maytham

Answer (score 1):

This is a log file permissions problem.

Some of the possible solutions:

- give write permissions to that file
- change the log file path to another you can write to
- change the log output driver
- disable logging

[How to configure log](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors%23configuration)

[How to deal with log file path and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions)