# After Installing Laravel Socialite app give blank page

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I'm new to laravel, i install Laravel Socialite through composer and do the necessary changes in config/app.php but when i run my app it give blank page, my app.php file is

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => 'http://localhost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => 'single',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider,


        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
        'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
        'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Socialize' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite,


    ],

];
```

Please help me to get out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Check your file permissions on storage/logs.

I was with the same problem with Socialite, and I found out that it was caused by Laravel's log rotation. It generates a new log file every day, but when you run from commandline (phpunit or artisan), it will generate this file with your Unix username, not www-data.

Your www-data user (or whatever webserver's user) needs permission to write in this file in order to write error logs. The blank screen is caused by the Logger trying to log an error before showing you the stack trace view.

As the script does not find love from the filesystem, the webserver stops its execution before it has the opportunity to tell you what is happening. So, you won't get Stack Trace or Laravel's Log even if your config is set to debug.

You can see it in your webserver's error log (if you're in Linux, it usually goes to /var/log/{server_name}/error.log - or check your virtual server logging configuration if the path is different).

After fixing the permission issue, you can see the trace view, find out the true error origin and then fix it.

If you do not want to re-fix this permission issue every day, just add your www-user to your username group, like this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G yourusername www-data
```

Or (if you prefer) you can config Monolog to add current username to the logfile, like answered here:
[Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions)