# What code handles the creation of laravel's daily logs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My daily logs have the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root    root    108384 Mar 29 00:30 laravel-2016-03-28.log
```

This causes a *Failed to open stream: Permission denied* error

If I delete the log file, it will be recreated with the correct permissions.

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 php-fpm php-fpm    819 Mar 28 18:04 laravel-2016-03-28.log
```

[This stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31719599/726312) seems to be working,

I added the following to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
/**
 * Configure Monolog.
 */
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $filename = storage_path('logs/laravel-'.php_sapi_name().'.log');
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
```

However, I still have new daily logs being created by root:root. These logs are not being used for anything. Where are these logs being created and why are they being created with root:root?

What code handles the creation of these daily logs?

Comment: Are you running Artisan commands as root?

Comment: @RojVroemen I'm not sure on that. I ran `crontab -e` as root and as our www-data but no artisan commands are showing up. Where does this Artisan command get run?