# How do I change the default file permissions for log files created by PHP Monologger?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, permissions, monolog

Laravel documentation shows that you can define custom configurations for your Monologger by placing the following code into your bootstrap/app.php file:

```
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler();
});
```

What are the possible custom configurations & syntaxes for them?

I'd like to change the daily log file's default permissions to 664 instead of the default 644, to avoid 'Permission denied' issues in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `FileHandler` and `RotatingFileHandler` you can easily set permission during construct. For RotatingFileHandler you have to set an optional parameter. These are parameters:

```
($filename, $maxFiles = 0, $level = Logger::DEBUG, $bubble = true, $filePermission = null, $useLocking = false)
```

A code like this will work for you:

```
$handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename,0,Logger::DEBUG,true,0664);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a personal opinion I will avoid altering the file permissions. What I usually do rather is create a different log file for the user needing to write to the Log. You will end up with more files but at least you know which file to look for what.

```
<?php
...

$app -> configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) {
  // Create a file name: laravel-user.log
  $filename = storage_path('logs/laravel-' . php_sapi_name() . '.log');
  // Pass that file name to your handler
  $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename);
  $monolog -> pushHandler($handler);
});

...
```

See these links for more info:

- [Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions)
- http://laravel.io/forum/02-11-2014-howto-log-with-mongodb