# Laravel monolog set user for log

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

Based on information from these 2 posts:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/log-file-permission-problem?page=1

[Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions)

I found a way how to resolve permissions problems with logs.

But still one problems remains: using this code I can configure permissions to created log file, but cannot do anything with user. Is there any way to create log that would belong to **www-data** user instead of me (root, etc)

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $filename = storage_path().'/logs/laravel_custom.log';
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename, 0, Logger::DEBUG,  true,  0777,  false);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
```

[image]

Edit1:I want to change user from "demaunt" to "www-data" withing monolog function

Comment: Do you use php-fpm? What's the user of php-fpm worker process?

Comment: 1) Yes
2) www-data