# Custom (dynamic) log file names with laravel5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

With laravel 5.5 we had access to `configureMonologUsing()` method in $app which made it possible for things like this in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function (Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
    $processName= $processUser['name'];

    $filename = storage_path('logs/laravel-' . php_sapi_name() . '-' . $processName . '.log');
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename);
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
});
```

Doing this is useful when your app may be called from different contexts (eg CLI/HTTP) with different users (which is desirable) and file rotation. Doing this prevents write errors in case the log file was created by the HTTP user before the CLI one tries to add something in it and vice-versa.

Handling this is otherwise tricky or insecure as it involves to be able to set write perms on files that may not exist yet.

In addition, it's quite handy to have logs separated by contexts as they usually have little in common and it makes it easier to search among them.

Unfortunately, this way of doing things is not possible anymore with laravel 5.6 and I could not (yet) find a way to transparently do so for all file based logging.

Thanks

Comment: Tumbleweed'd :o

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Customisation is now done through invoking a custom formatter for Monolog.

Here is an example using daily rotating filenames (as I do).

This can be setup in `config/logging.php`, note the non-default `tap` parameter:

```
'channels' => [

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomFilenames::class],
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

]
```

In your custom formatter, you can manipulate the Monolog logger however you wish, similar to `configureMonologUsing()`:

`app\Logging\CustomFilenames.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;

class CustomFilenames
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof RotatingFileHandler) {
                $sapi = php_sapi_name();
                $handler->setFilenameFormat("{filename}-$sapi-{date}", 'Y-m-d');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One way to restore your original behaviour is to remove the `{date}` component from the handler's `filenameFormat`. A better way might be to manipulate the appropriate handler for the `single` driver.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#advanced-monolog-channel-customization

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's for sure not the way to go with containers, but it's very handy in good old physical servers

Answer (score 8):

Solution:

step1: create a channel inside the config/logging.php file

example :

```
'channels' => [
    'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single', 
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],

'web' => [
      'driver' => 'single',
      'path' => storage_path('logs/web/web.log'),
   ],

]
```

> Step2: Now set dyanamic path from controller  like this

```
config(['logging.channels.web.path' => storage_path('logs/web/'.time().'.log')]);
```

> Step3 : now generate your log

```
  Log::channel('web')->info("your message goes here");
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: not good idea , you have to set log in all controller.

Comment: @Kundan roy: Does this work with Lumen(incl. latest versions) too ? I don't see `config/logging.php` in Lumen, does this file have to be added manually ?