# How to change permission of daily logs in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, server

I have created daily logs. But its permission is read-only. I made its permission to 666 manually. Its working fine for now. But the next day, when a new log is created with old permission. How to setup permission in laravel application for automating this?

Answer (score 0):

try to give 777 permission to your storage/log folder

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions