# Laravel: consulting queue failed because today's log file could not be opened

Tags: php, laravel, logging, permissions

### Why question is not a duplicate

"Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions" question is starting from a different situation. I already have user member of www-data and already my processes are running as www-data and not creating file as root or as different group. So suggested solution is not enough.

Please, see my own answer to see the most simple solution to this *common* situation.

---

My storage/logs directory is configured as

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 user www-data 4096 Aug 21 14:39 logs
```

> Note the sticky bit

Single log files are being created automatically as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2381004 Aug 21 14:51 laravel-2019-08-21.log
```

Note, also, that my `user` is a member of group `www-data`.

### The problem

accessing on ssh as `user` , I cannot run `php artisan queue:failed` because I got this error

```
   UnexpectedValueException  : The stream or file "/var/www/app/storage/logs/laravel-2019-08-21.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

  at /var/www/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
    103|             }
    104|             restore_error_handler();
    105|             if (!is_resource($this->stream)) {
    106|                 $this->stream = null;
  > 107|                 throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The stream or file "%s" could not be opened: '.$this->errorMessage, $this->url));
    108|             }
    109|         }
    110|
    111|         if ($this->useLocking) {
```

### Question

I cannot force server to create log file as `user:www-data`

But I need to be able to read *and_write* them. Or, at minimum, I need to able to run `queue:*` commands

How should I fix this bad server config?

> I'm using Debian 10.0

Comment: Can you use `sudo` to change your user (i.e. do you have the permissions)? `sudo -u www-data php artisan queue:failed`

Comment: The File is readable by all, but only writeable by the original user, so the group won't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674597/laravel-daily-log-created-with-wrong-permissions)

Comment: The top answers are not that helpful, but `setfacl` and the `permission` setting are.

Comment: The answers sort differently between my logged-in browser and non-logged in browser, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379249/1007220 should be fairly helpful

Comment: I understand both causes and other suggested solutions but all not applicable ! My solution is simply and works, but this requires that user must be member of www-data group. And in my case this is already true.

Comment: @aynber: added explanation of why it's not a duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

I resolved specifying in Laravel `config/logging.php` the file permission mask.

```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
        'permissions' => 0664
    ],
```

The important part is

`'permissions' => 0664`.

> Important: Respect the format !
>
> `0664` != `664`

So now `user` can also write logs.

> Note: this works only because `user` it's member of `www-data` group!