# Default create log files with 664 permissions

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

How can I configure my Laravel or Ubuntu server so my Laravel logger creates a log file with the 664 permissions? Right now it defaults to 644.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `config\logging.php` file and add `permission` key to your default log channel. Is seems that this feature is available from [Laravel 5.6.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379249/9618184).

**Example:**

```
return [
    'channels' => [
        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'permission' => 0664, // this is the new key to add
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Notes:**

- in this example the default log channel is `single`
- make sure the `permission` key has the value *without quotes* and *with leading zero*. read more about this in [php manual of chmod](https://www.php.net/chmod)