# Configuring Laravel to Create Log Files with Specific Permissions and Ownership

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, logging, laravel-artisan

How can I configure Laravel to create log files with specific permissions, such as -rw-rw-r--, instead of the default permissions, -rw-r--r--? I want the log files to be owned by www-data:www-data instead of root:root upon creation."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `config/logging.php` file. For example:

```php
'channels' => [
    'single' => [
        'permission' => 0664,
    ],
],
```

The `permission` option is set to **0664**, which corresponds to the desired permissions **`-rw-rw-r--`** .

Also see this questions:

- [Laravel daily log created with wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27674597/10542740)
- [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30639174/10542740)